# Access X11 display

Tags: linux, x11, rhel

I'm using a CIS that automatically run build and tests. The tests are working fine with Windows, but when run in rhel it throwed X11 Display variable not set.

I made sure X11 is installed and I can get back the xclock by using Xmanager. The intention is not to push the display to client but I used Xmanager to verify if X11 is installed.

When the display is not exported, the tests that uses graphics fails but when I `set export DISPLAY=0.0`, it threw `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/awt/X11GraphicsEnvironment`

[This source](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/904preview/uixhelp/uixdevguide/xserver.html) says the cNF exception is misleading.

Here is the scrap of that content:

> Unfortunately, this error message is somewhat misleading. This message does not actually reflect a class loading problem. The error can be avoiding by setting the DISPLAY environment variable in the appropriate configuration file.

This means the display is not exported properly but the test does not report of missing X11 Display. What am I missing to do?

Suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: The subject of the question is not very instructive (and not a question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure from your description if you want to run the tests without X11. In that case, you could use [headless mode](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/) to tell AWT that you don't want graphic output. That should allow your tests to run if they are not interactive.

I can't see how you can be able to run things like xclock, but not Java. Is there any intermediate step missing? Do you ssh into the host that should run the tests?

Comment: Hi ShiDoiSi, thanks for the reply! I want the tests to be run with X11 enabled. The server checks out the code from svn, builds and runs the tests. I don't ssh into the server for running the test. Tests run periodically or when some one checks in svn.

Comment: I used Xmanager using ssh just to confirm if the server can display graphics.

Comment: The integration server has a separate account in the Linux server, should that account needs any special access to use the X11 environment?

Comment: @Mohan Do you log into that other account with ssh, or do you use any other way, like 'su'? Did you verify that you can start e.g. xclock from that account?

Comment: Yes, I log into my account with ssh. I have not verified it by running xclock from that account. I just tried it from my account. i'll check that. Thanks!

Comment: @Mohan While you are at it, you might also want to report on the (sanitized) output of ssh -v ... as you log in. There should be a message about whether X-forwarding is enabled or not in there.

Comment: All, using xhost I gave permission to the account that I use to run the automated tests. An now I get a CNF exception related to X11. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11.XToolkit

Comment: Did you run the test I mentioned above, e.g. starting xclock? Get this to work before proceeding to Java.

Answer (score 2):

**export DISPLAY=0.0**

This is a syntax error. You must use:
`export DISPLAY=:0.0`

(Note the colon.)

Once that is right you'll need to ensure the user your tests run as has permissions to the X server.  See `xauth` or for insecure but trivial testing `xhost +`.

Comment: Hey Nathan, I use the command with the colon, its a typo in the question. I will need ti check using xauth or xhost+. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an X display running?

One common way to get a display for automated tests is to use the Xvfb "fake" display server. Run Xvfb, then set DISPLAY pointing to it.

Comment: I tried installing xvfb but had lot of conflicts, I'll try to install it if other options doesn't work